# Build with TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with mixed Platforms

Tags: msbuild, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm moving to a new TFS server on a 64 bit machine (Windows Server 2008 R2). My problem is that now some solution (WinForms with another class library projects) are failing.

In my first attempt, I tried Release|Any CPU in the Process Tab of the Build definition Window, but with this configuration my WinForms project gets skipped.

Then I tried changing the "platform target" to x86 in all the class libraries projects in the Projects properties in Visual Studio, (I can not change the active platform to x86 in the Build tab on the IDE), then in the configuration manager of the solution changed the platform to x86 and selected the class libraries (when I changed to x86 all the class libraries were deselected since in there all the class libraries appears as Any CPU in the platform) and also changed the platform to Release|X86 in the build definition of TFS, but then I get this error

> "SGEN: An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: E:\Builds\Temp\4\69\Binaries\Cnbv.Sait.Itildesa.ControlItems.dll."

Then I tried with a mixed configuration in the solution (reverted all the changes) and also changed the platform to Release|Mixed Platforms in the build definition of TFS but I get the same error now with the exe

> (SGEN: An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: E:\Builds\Temp\3\69\Sources\Dev\Desarrollo\Code\Sources\Cnbv.Sait.Itildesa\obj\x86\Release\Sait.Itildesa.exe.)

What is the correct way to build a mixed configuration on a 64 bit machine?, I can't leave the configuration/platform empty because if someone checks-in in Debug then that's what gets built.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 too, but no strange problem. I guess this problem is not related to your windows/machine at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the MSBUILD platform to x86 in the build definition, my bad.